# Hats that escape a user's profile picture are inconsistently above/below other UI elements

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash

Pretty much self-explanatory. The "hat" is above some UI elements (links, bio), but below some others (tab titles), which looks weird.

[image: screenshot]

Same thing when hovering over items:

[image: screenshot 2]